# Is it possible to login with Facebook LoginManager with both Read and Publish permissions?

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-android-sdk

I'm creating an Android app where you should be able to login with facebook with both read and publish permissions. I implemented it with the [LoginManager](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/android/current/class/LoginManager/) and it works well enough. This is my method that logs into facebook:

```
 /**
 * Attempts to log the user into facebook and to get an access token.
 */
private void facebookLogin() {
    callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();

    LoginManager loginManager = LoginManager.getInstance();
    loginManager.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookLoginCallback());
    loginManager.logInWithReadPermissions(this, Constants.FB_READ_PERMISSIONS);
    loginManager.logInWithPublishPermissions(this, Constants.FB_PUBLISH_PERMISSIONS);
}
```

I noticed after a while though that this code snippets launches two separate Facebook logins on top of each other, when one is completed the other is still in the background. If I only login with read permissions (or only with publish) I only need to login once, which is what I want.

I do however need both types of permissions. I looked through the Facebook Android Login [guide](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/android) where they claim that you should use the LoginButton since it can store the permissions required and then get all in one login. Is this not possible with the LoginManager? I looked all over the internet and [this](https://mobikul.com/login-and-register-via-facebook/) is the only place that says that the LoginManager logs in with read **or** publish but the LoginButton can do both.

Is all this true? It's not a huge job to change the login from LoginManager to LoginButton, but I just wanted to know if there isn't any way to log in with both read and publish permissions at once with the LoginManager, it seems so strange that this isn't possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it myself.

I completely misunderstood how the facebook login worked, but after reading up on the facebook api I finally fixed it.

If you need both Read and publish permissions you need to ask for them on separate occations. When I first log into the app I only ask for read permissions with the loginManager (as I did before). Only when the user posts content to facebook I check if the user has publishing permissions. If not, I start a new loginManager and ask for it.

Since the user has already logged in once, the user simply needs to approve the publishing permissions, so it's no hassle.